# Two elements with the same height with jQuery - all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm taking advantage of a system of gallery I found on the web, where, depending on the proximity of the image of the mouse, it grows proportionally.

Link: [Gallery](http://retroplus.esy.es/HTML/)

Well, I adapted the code to be responsive (and as you can see is under construction) and there is no apparent problem. My problem starts when changing the resolution (either using the zoom browser, is 'spinning' the tablet or mobile). Hovering or clicking (with touchs) on top of any image, in its resolution whose page has loaded, describing nothing happens, but when it gives a small zoom, you can already see all the misalignment description with images . The image height is equal to the width. The width is relative.

I figured a single solution to my problem: using jQuery. I program with a basic level - intermediate in this framework and can do good things. But I have no idea of how when change the resolution, change the size of the description automatically. To date, use this code to let both equal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".gallery-description").height( $(".gallery-thumbs li a img").height());
});
```

I hope someone can help me improving the function or giving other suggestions! Thanks. :)

Comment: You're looking for the `resize` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just respond to `resize`:

```
$(document).ready(resizeGallery);
$(window).resize(resizeGallery);
function resizeGallery() {
    $(".gallery-description").height( $(".gallery-thumbs li a img").height());
}
```

Comment: Need to adapt the code a bit, but it worked. Thank you very much! :)